# Data.Array's // operator priority

Tags: arrays, haskell, types

I have noticed that in the following example:

```
incrementByIndices :: Array Int Int -> [Int] -> Array Int Int
incrementByIndices arr indices = arr // zip indices (map (\i -> arr!i + 1) indices)
```

zip doesn't have to be surrounded by parenthesis. Why is that so? `:i (//)` didn't show different priority for `//` so I assume it's regular function application. Why don't I have a type check error stating that `zip` can't be `//`'s argument?

Contrary to:

```
nub nub [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Function application binds tighter than any operator, so your expression doesn't need parentheses for the same reason that, say, this one doesn't:

```
zip [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8] ++ zip [20,30] [30,40]
```

The priority and fixity of `(//)` isn't important at all here!

Comment: What's the terminology? Is an operator a function in infix form?

Comment: @egdmitry Essentially, although you can convert. `++` is an operator symbol which is an operator by default, and `zip` is an identifier, but `(++)` can be used as an identifier (you can even have `let (++) = 2 in (++)+(++)`) and `\`zip\` ` is an operator. See [the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-240003.2).

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html) mentions a precedence of `9`:

```
(//) :: Ix i => Array i e -> [(i, e)] -> Array i e     | infixl 9 |
```

Comment: Thanks! It's weird that `:i` didn't show the precedence, so I assumed it was standard.

Comment: @egdmitry `infixl 9` *is* the default precedence for any operator or function used infix, so it doesn't get listed.